# change minimum transaction log file size

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have a database that was setup with poor default transaction log sizes (by me unfortunately) now I want to change those defaults permanently.  I'm using the following script which seems to work but not permanently.

```
use master

ALTER DATABASE [MyDB]
MODIFY FILE (NAME=MyDB_log,SIZE=10000MB,MAXSIZE=UNLIMITED,FILEGROWTH=1000MB);
```

When I'm working on my laptop with some large transactions I want to Shrink the log file back to this 10GB size when I'm done so I don't run out of disk space but when I do the shrink the log file it shrinks back to 8MB.  Another database I have that I setup properly shrinks back to the 10GB size that I setup when I created it.

How can I force the default to be 10GB?

A lot of other posts are people trying to shink their log file to small size **this is NOT that**, I want to keep my local database log file to this large file size on purpose and do not wish it to ever be smaller than that.

Also, even though the script above is setting MAXSIZE to UNLIMITED when I look at the log file properties it is still capped at 2GB (which I did not set and in any case my setting to UNLIMITED doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

Why not specific the size to shrink it to?

```
USE {Your Database};
GO

DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'{Your Log File Name}' , 10000);
```

Obviously replacing values in braces (`{}`).

Comment: yeah I know but why do I have to?  Surely running the above script should just force the new default?